# about sequence diagram for multi-threads java application

Tags: java, multithreading, uml, diagram, sequence-diagram

I want to draw sequence diagram for a multi-threads java application. Do you think a sequence diagram is Ok for a multi-threads java application(If so, I don't know how to do that as of now, any tutorials?)? Or should I draw multi-diagrams for multi-threads: one seqeunce diagram ties to a thread?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to illustrate multiple threads in sequence diagram?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643733/how-to-illustrate-multiple-threads-in-sequence-diagram)

Comment: There are already some answers here,  but none about specific multi-threading features in sequence-diagrams.  This other more specific question may also be of interest to you https://stackoverflow.com/q/46318979/3723423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say to draw a sequence diagram per thread.

Trying to get multiple threads into a single sequence diagram doesn't make a whole lot of sense since events are occurring in parallel, not in sequence.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of diagram is called "[Petri net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net)". It describes where concurrent processes (threads) synchronize and which parts run in parallel.

You can then explain each node in the Petri net using a sequence diagram.

Comment: Indeed, this is a possibility.  You may however consider uml activity-diagrams which are rooted in petri nets but provide some more advanced (and standardised) features.

Answer (score 0):

There is the option of having the sequence diagrams created for you by a tool. I work on an Eclipse plugin called [Diver: Dynamic Interactive Views For Reverse Engineering](http://eclipsediver.wordpress.com) that will generate sequence diagrams for the various threads of your Java program automatically in Eclipse.

It lets you:

- Easily trace your Java programs
- Visualize your program’s runtime functionality
- Filter your traces and sequence diagrams to make them more compact
- Filter your IDE based on what methods are called at runtime
- See what code ran in your source code editors