# How to represent messages for unordered actions in the global sequence diagramme of my application

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

In my application i have several actions that the user can perform like : displaying items, search items, purchase items.. there isn't any unique sequence which the user should follow specifically to finally perform the checkout. So i wonder how i can represent all these actions through messages all along a unique life cycle of my system and i don't know if i can just and simply choose any order for them but i don't think it will be a good and suitable representation of my user-system interactions if i cannot at least indicate that the order of these actions can be performed randomly by the user.

[Multi-threading representation in a sequence diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643733/how-to-illustrate-multiple-threads-in-sequence-diagram#) cannot be solution for my problem because these actions aren't supposed to be parallels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Kirill Fakhroutdinov's example of [UML Interaction Overview Diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/interaction-overview-diagrams.html)

[image]

Sequence diagram is just one of the set of [UML Behavior Diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html#behavior-diagram), it is not 1 size fits all solution.

You can find some more links to what I consider useful in UML behavior modeling in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23301076/2626313)