# UML: How to Model UI and Background-Threads for Mobile Application (iPhone/iOS, Android)

Tags: iphone, android, ios, uml, background-process

There are some Topics on Stackoverflow already related on how to model different Threads in UML, for example: [Is there an inituitive UML approach to depict threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954193/is-there-an-inituitive-uml-approach-to-depict-threads).

However I still feel, that my case has not been already discussed, even though it should be pretty common:

I am creating an iPhone Application, where I am obviously have a Main-UI-Thread and I am also using Background-Threads to perform Remote-Calls, etc. I basically have 4 different aspects that I like to display within my diagramm:

1. The UI that is shown to the User.
2. The Tasks that are being performed by the Main-UI-Thread (therefore blocking the UI)
3. The Tasks that are performed by Background-Threads
4. Updates of the UI, which are performed by the UI-Thread, but can be triggered by Background-Threads. For example: new Information loaded from Server, which needs to be displayed on the UI

Has anybody ran into a similiar issue and therefore might show me an example or give me some best practises on how to solve my problem? I am not even sure if I should use a sequence-diagram, an activity-diagram or maybe even some other type.

Answer (score 1):

Well Pascal,

This  is not an UML question. It is a design question.

UML just helps you

> To understand hard and crtical section of your program/design and   to
>   explore alternative solutions , while **writing your code.** with the power of visual modeling.

So..

> First, ask yourself what kind of parallelism or concurrency  exist in
>   your problem?  **To investigate this**:
>
> **Draw a simple activity diagram** with partions in which each partions
>   used to represent different operating system threads or processes.The
>   object nodes can be used to model the shared objects and data.Forking can be used to model the creation and parallel execution of multiple threads or processes.

**Then ask yourself(using that diagram)**

> What are my shared data? What are my active classes? (threads)What kind of "concurency" problems" may
>   accour? What may go wrong? What are synronization points? etc..Based on this Explore different alternatives, designs.

**The last thing you should worry is UML and its sytax(symbols)**.

The best UML diagrams are the one that wake up the desire of "asking question" in your mind.

At first forget about Uml. Ask core questions about your problem. **If you like visual modeling and your mind like visual thinking use Uml for better understand and investigate possible design** solutions.

**UML can not design for you...**

Answer (score 1):

I found this research papers while searching for same thing

[M-UML: an extension to UML for the modeling of mobile
agent-based software systems](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.86.1320&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

May be it can help you